# Formatting data for CoreImage CIColorCube

Tags: iphone, core-image

I'm trying to apply arbitrary 3D Luts to images on iOS, but I'm stuck.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to correctly format the cube data for CIColorCube.

I've done what I can based on the brief screen grabs I've taken from the WWDC videos, but what I really need is some sort of working template to go from.
Are there any docs with an example of a hard coded cube rather than the procedural ICC generated ones shown in the ImageApp sample code?

Right now my cube data looks like what you see below (with the middle chopped out for brevity).
Its throwing the error:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<CIColorCube 0xb46a850> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputCubedata.'"
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm tearing my hear out over this one. I can't find any sold examples of what CIColorCube is expecting (As in a working example, not just a explanation).

```
uint8_t color_cube_data[4096*4] = {
    0, 0, 0, 1,
    17, 0, 0, 1,
    33, 0, 0, 1,
    51, 0, 0, 1,
    68, 0, 0, 1,
    84, 0, 0, 1,
    102, 0, 0, 1,
    119, 0, 0, 1,
-----etc etc etc
    153, 255, 255, 1,
    170, 255, 255, 1,
    186, 255, 255, 1,
    204, 255, 255, 1,
    221, 255, 255, 1,
    237, 255, 255, 1,
    255, 255, 255, 1
};
```

Comment: Did that color_cube_data work? If so, would you mind sharing the full lookup table?

Answer (score 2):

I can't help with all your problems without more info, but I think your current error may be cause by this.  Make sure the line of code setting your cube data reads like this...

[_colorCube setValue:color_cube_data forKey:@"**inputCubeData**"];

not this...

[_colorCube setValue:color_cube_data forKey:@"**inputCubedata**"];

Answer (score 1):

3D LUT has to be wrapped into NSData before passed as an argument to the CIFilter. Cube values are in range [0.0 : 1.0]

```
NSData * cube_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:color_cube_data length:4096*sizeof(float)*4];

[filter setValue:input_image forKey:@"inputImage"];
[filter setValue:cube_data forKey:@"inputCubeData"];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16] forKey:@"inputCubeDimension"];
```

Value for inputCubeDimension is strictly power of two.

Comment: If you are getting strange colors out of your CIColorCube, it may well be that your size is not a power of two. Mine were coming out with all their blue components set to zero.